# Exclude nil values from ElasticSearch Aggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filtering, aggregation

I was using this query to retrieve the most significant values:

```
keywords = Answer.search( 
    :size => 5, 
    :query => { 
        :match => {
            :question_id => 32481
         }
    }, 
    :aggregations => { 
        :keywords => { 
            :significant_terms => {
                :field => 'text'
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The field is :text, but it has nil values, so the answer is always:

```
2.1.2 :135 > keywords.map(&:text)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

I tried to add a filter, as [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html) suggests, but it gives me a parse error:

```
keywords = Answer.search( 
    :size => 5, 
    :query => { 
        :match => {
            :question_id => 32481
         },
         :filtered => {
             :filter => {
                 :exists => { :field => 'text' }
             }
         }
    }, 
    :aggregations => { 
        :keywords => { 
            :significant_terms => {
                :field => 'text'
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I've tried many combinations, with no success. How can I get only the valid text answers?

Comment: Try keywords.map(&:text).compact

Comment: I believe that is not the solution. Im getting a parse error from the elasticsearch with that latter query. The compact method on the first result would only return me an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your ES query should translate to something like this:

```
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match": { "question_id" : 32481 } },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keywords": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "text"
      }
    }
  }
```

meaning your "question_id" "match" should be enclosed in the "filtered" element.